# Shortcut of finding a tangent line and tangent point to a curve that's explicitly or implicitly defined

Tags: geometry

Any shortcut command of finding a tangent line and tangent point to a curve that's explicitly or implicitly defined? The focus is on implicit curves.

An implicit curve could be sth like $(x/exp(y)-1)^2-y^2=1$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: In general on this site we expect a concrete presentation of the task at hand, namely a proper mathematical formulation and some attempt made by you in code form. Also, we like having well-defined threads that deal with one problem at a time. Having said that, please take a moment to edit your question such that it meets the general guidelines of the site.

Comment: The question is clear enough. If anyone knows of a Mathematica function that does this he can share. If not, there is no reason to complain about it.

Comment: thanks for supporting! The best mathematical exercise is through communication without using equations. If a question is explained clearly enough, there is no need to use equations. The shorter the question the better, saving people's time.

Comment: @feyman But answering might be simplified if you do some work before. For example what is the implicit form of your curve, are you looking for 3D-curve?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann it's a 2D curve and I added an example in the question

Comment: @feynman Thanks, that makes it easier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

- For the implicit form of curve `f[x,y]==0`, the normal of the tangent line is `Grad[f[x,y],{x,y}]`, so the tangent line of the `f[x,y]==0` is

```
({x, y} - {x0, y0}) . Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] == 0
```

Here `{x0,y0}` is the arbitary pont on the tangent line.

- We use `ImplicitRegion` and `DiscretizeRegion` to solve the equation.(since `NSolve`,`Reduce` or `FindRoot` does not work for this case)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_, y_] = (x - Exp[y] - 1)^2 - y^2 - 1;
{x0, y0} = {-5, -3};
reg = ImplicitRegion[{({x, y} - {x0, y0}) . Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] == 
     0, f[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}];
pts = MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[reg, {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], 
   0][[;; , 1]]
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0 // Evaluate, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {Blue, Point[{x0, y0}], Red, Point[pts], Red, 
   Arrowheads[{{.05, .8}}], Arrow[{{x0, y0}, #}] & /@ pts}]
```

[image]

- We can test the pont `{x0, y0} = {1, 1}`, there are three tangent lines through `{x0,y0}={1,1}`.( so there are three tangent points)

[image]

- animation.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Manipulate[
 Module[{f, reg, dreg, pts},
  f[x_, y_] = (x - Exp[y] - 1)^2 - y^2 - 1;
  {x0, y0} = pt;
  reg = ImplicitRegion[{({x, y} - {x0, y0}) . Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] ==
       0, f[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}];
  pts = MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[reg, {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], 
     0][[;; , 1]];
  ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0 // Evaluate, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   Epilog -> {Blue, Point[{x0, y0}], Red, Point[pts], Red, 
     Arrowheads[{{.05, .8}}], Arrow[{{x0, y0}, #}] & /@ pts}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]], {{pt, {0, 0}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

**Original**

It seems that it is not easy to find all of the tangent lines for any point `{x0,y0}` outside the curve. Here we only plot one tangent line from a point does not on the curve.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_, y_] = (x - Exp[y] - 1)^2 - y^2 - 1;
{x0, y0} = {-5, -3};
sol = FindInstance[{({x, y} - {x0, y0}) . Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
   f[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}, Reals, 1]
pts = {x, y} /. sol // N
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0 // Evaluate, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {Blue, Point[{x0, y0}], Red, Point[pts], Red, 
   Arrow[{{x0, y0}, #}] & /@ pts}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the Applications section in the documentation for [`ImplicitD`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitD.html). Note that `ImplicitD` has been available only since version 13.1.

```
(* Define your curve *)
curve = (x - Exp[y] - 1)^2 - y^2 == 1;

(* Calculate the appropriate partial derivative *)
slope = ImplicitD[curve, y, x];

(* Find points on the curve at x = -1 and x = 4 *)
points = FindInstance[curve && (x == -1 || x == 4), {x, y}, Reals, 4];

(* Define tangent lines *)
tangents = InfiniteLine[{x, y}, {1, slope}] /. points;

(* Plot the curve and tangent lines *)
Show[ContourPlot @@ {curve, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}}, 
 Graphics[{{Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{x, y}] /. points}, {Orange,
     Dashed, tangents}}]]
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_, y_] = (x - Exp[y] - 1)^2 - y^2 - 1;
df = ImplicitD[f[x0, y0] == 0, y0, x0];
pts = NSolve[f[x0, y0] == 0 && (x0 == -1 || x0 == 4), {x0, y0}, Reals]
{{x0 -> -1., y0 -> -1.9024}, {x0 -> 4., y0 -> -2.76129},
{x0 -> 4., y0 -> 0.60499}, {x0 -> 4., y0 -> 1.58371}}

tangent = (x - x0)*df + y0 /. pts // Expand
{-0.935624 + 0.966771 x, 1.79955 - 1.14021 x,
-1.09796 + 0.425737 x, 0.590528 + 0.248296 x}

Show[Plot[tangent, {x, -3, 6}, PlotStyle -> Dashed, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize -> Large, Point[{x0, y0} /. pts]}], 
 ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -5, 6}, {y, -5, 5}, ContourStyle -> Thick], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

For versions below 13.1 you can replace ImplicitD with the following version:

```
df = -D[f[x0, y0], x0]/D[f[x0, y0], y0] // Simplify
```

**A shortcut command of finding a tangent line is given by ResourceFunction:**

```
tangent = ResourceFunction["TangentLine"];
```

The function is bijective at x = -1.

```
tangent[(x - Exp[y] - 1)^2 - y^2 == 1, {x, -1}, y] // N // Dataset
```

[image]

At x = 4 the function is surjective. You get only one tangentline at [4, 0.60499].

```
tangent[(x - Exp[y] - 1)^2 - y^2 == 1, {x, 4}, y] // N // Dataset
```

[image]
[image]

There is a note in the description:

> If only one coordinate of the intersection point is given, the other
> coordinate is inferred. For expressions that are multivalued at the
> given value of x or y, information on only one of potentially several
> tangent lines is returned.